# How to use GROUP_CONACT and CONCAT in mysql sub query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I  want to retrieve table records in single quotes with comma separated values and using this output  as sub query inside main query to get  records but my subquery is not working however writing separate two queries working fine, but I want to use single query instead of two queries.

Mysql query  to get single quote values with comma separated:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (CONCAT('''', date(created_on), '''' ))) as 
 strengths FROM table WHERE created_on BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-04'
```

output:

```
'2020-08-01','2020-08-03'
```

Expected same output but using mysql subquery  :  (below query not retrieving records)

```
 SELECT * FROM `report` where created_on in (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
   (CONCAT('''', date(created_on), '''' ))) FROM report WHERE created_on BETWEEN 
   '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-04') order by created_on
```

Comment: WHERE IN needs literals list. GROUP_CONCAT produces one literal. Use FIND_IN_SET().

Comment: @Akina can you please  show me  in subquery way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If do formally, then

```
SELECT * 
FROM report 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( DATE(created_on), 
                   ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT DATE(created_on)) 
                     FROM report 
                     WHERE created_on BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-04' 
                   )
                 ) 
ORDER BY created_on
```

From the other side - subquery selects all dates in specifies dates range which are present in the table. Outer query selects rows which dates are present in this list, i.e. is present in the table. So ALL table rows within the range will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT * FROM report 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(
        CONCAT('''', DATE(created_on), '''' ), 
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('''', DATE(created_on), '''' )) FROM report WHERE DATE(created_on) BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-04')
      )
```

because `GROUP_CONCAT()` returns a string which is a comma separated list.
If the column's `created_on` data type is DATE then you can change all `DATE(created_on)` to just `created_on`.